# Jquery override 'click' event only for a child object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.child1', function(event) {
// do whatever
});

$('.parent').on('click', '.child2', function(event) {
// do whatever
});
```

This works well, even though both 'click' events are attributed to parent, it won't override. Now the function runs multiple times on my page, having the same effect as this:

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.child1', function(event) {
// do whatever
});

$('.parent').on('click', '.child1', function(event) {
// do whatever
});
```

When running twice, the event won't override, but add. So I'll get the function running 2 times on every click. Not my desired behavior (only 1 execution), to stop them from duplicating the events, I would normally do:

```
$('.parent').off('click').on('click', '.child1', function(event) {
// do whatever
});

$('.parent').off('click').on('click', '.child2', function(event) {
// do whatever
});
```

In this case, the second .off('click') removes the click from .child1 and overrides, even though the second is just related to .child2 and not .child1. So, in other words, even though both events act on clicks for separate children of .parent, they override if I use the 'off' technique.

My question is: how to override an event only for one specific child, so that if I run the same declaration twice, it won't duplicate the event?

PS: I can't do $('.child').click() because children are loaded dynamically, so I need to attach the event on the static .parent.

Comment: You can't __override__  the event handler

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. You're asking about a flawed solution instead of stating the problem you're trying to solve. What is the behaviour you need to achieve?

Comment: There is  no way to target the desired children and off click for it? I see that you want to do that for a specific element so you can add a class or an attribute for help to target

Comment: IMO, defining `.on("click")` multiple times is a bad design. Just define it once, at the top of your script, instead of trying to cancel it then re-bind it multiple times. It's delegated, so it will work even on dynamically added elements anyway, so you just need to bind it once.

Comment: Good design in this case works pretty well on static websites. With dynamic elements, you might need to re-bind something, that's why it may be called multple times.

Comment: Your syntax in the first block should actually work. Can you check again if your child2 div is not inside child1? The event fires two times because of the event bubbling phase. Such quirks can also occur if you have unmatching divs or incorrect nesting.

Comment: Yes, but if .parent is deleted and recreated, which is the case, then you'd have to rebind. In this case, following the proposed good design would be to attach all events to document, but then, it would also be bad design. Sometimes we just gotta choose the 'least worse' choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
$(document).off('click','.parent').on('click', '.child1', function(event) {
    alert("click1");
});

$(document).off('click','.parent').on('click', '.child2', function(event) {
alert("click2");
});
```